# iOS Today Extension UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8-today-widget

My today extension (RSS Reader on picture) is not showing anything if table view is added (I have tried multiple prototype cells and also dynamically). I am using storyboards. I have been reading several articles and I watched video from WWDC 2014 and all mentioned, that today extension is "based" on view controllers but I guess I must be missing something.

There is nothing I could show you in code. Simply If I add a table view then extension is showing nothing.

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to set the height of the widget by setting self.preferredContentsize to equal content size of the tableview. This has to be done in your controller.

```
self.preferredContentSize = self.tableView.contentSize;
```